# Encode unique node with multi parents

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Suppose we have this structure:

```
<listing>
         <fields>
               <field name="id" style=""...>
               ...
         </fields> 
</listing>
<crud>
      <fields>
               <field name="id" style=""...>
               ...
      </fields> 
</crud>
```

is there a way to avoid the repetition of the same field?

Comment: You don't what the same `field` to be shown twice?  You are looking for one to be a reference to the other?

Comment: yes, it the same object, it should be stored once i think unless its a duplication

Comment: i am trying to use another list childrenIds to identify children with there ids, but i dont know if its is the best solution

Comment: i post my solution could tell me what do you think Blaise

Comment: I have added an answer that may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24738978/383861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an instance is referenced more than once you can leverage `@XmlID` & `@XmlIDREF`. These annotations allow you to reference an instance leveraging a foreign key (an objects key is identified using the `@XmlID` annotation, and the reference using the `@XmlIDREF` annotation).

I have written more about this use case on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html